# Don't want to display all RecursiveDirectoryIterator files to user

Tags: php

I have a form which the user inputs a file name into.  It iterates through all the directories successfully looking to match the users search input to the relevant pdf file.

When it finds the match it correctly echos 'it matches' and breaks out of the foreach loop. However, it also correctly states 'not a match' for all the files it finds before it matches the correct file.  So I get a long list of 'not a match ' followed by 'it matches'.

If I echo " " instead of 'not a match' it works fine and doesn't display anything but I would like to tell the user only once that what they have inputted does not match.  I am sure I have overlooked something basic but any assistance would be greatly appreciated on how to achieve this.

Here is the code I have.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['target'])) {
   $searchInput = $_POST['target']; 
   $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/myDirectory/");

   foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {       
       $path_info = pathinfo($file);
       $extension = $path_info['extension'];  

       if (strcmp("pdf", $extension) == 0) {
           $lowerInput = strtolower($searchInput); 

           if (!empty($path_info)) {
               $string = strtolower($path_info['filename']);
               if(preg_match("~\b" . $lowerInput. "\b~", $string)) {
                   echo "it matches <br>";
                   break;
               } else {
                   if (!preg_match("~\b" . $lowerInput . "\b~", $string)) { 
                       echo "not a match  <br>";
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   } //end foreach
} // end if submit pressed
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Search Files</h3>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  id="searchform">
            Type the File You Require:<br><br>

            <input id="target" type="text" name="target" required >
            <br>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've left out some of your code, just showing the parts that matter.  Basically just set a variable and echo it once when the `foreach` completes.

```
$msg="Not a match  <br>" ;
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
    ...
    if(preg_match("~\b" . $lowerInput. "\b~", $string)) {
        $msg = "it matches <br>" ;
        break ;
    }
    // no need for an else clause, "not a match" is default finding
}// end of foreach
echo $msg ;
```

Comment: Thank you works perfectly.  Makes total sense to remove the else clause. Thanks again!!!